# How to change voice formant?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, voice, sox

Trying to change a voice with python on linux I found that I can change the pitch:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.wav -af asetrate=44100*3/4,atempo=4/3,aresample=44100 2.wav
```

or

```
sox <infile> <outfile> pitch <shift>
```

The question is how to change the formant. There is a `rubberband wrapper` for `ffmpeg` which suppose to do that but there is no example in google.

Answer (score -3):

you have to copy or to code your new sound

example 1: inpu1 1.wav will transform the voice and code into flac file

ffmpeg -i 1.wav -af asetrate=44100*3/4,atempo=4/3,aresample=44100  *-codec:a flac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -sample_fmt s16 2.flac*

[example 1 in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKVvf.png)

example 2 (and this is you fail):

ffmpeg -i 1.wav -af asetrate=44100*3/4,atempo=4/3,aresample=44100 *-c copy* 2.wav

if continue fails, just try

ffmpeg -i 1.wav -af asetrate=44100*3/4,atempo=4/3,aresample=44100 *-c copy -strict -2* 2.wav

Comment: Question is asking about [formants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant), not formats. Why recommend `-strict -2`? There is no experimental status associated with PCM/WAV encoding that I am aware of.

Comment: @xear please replase your answer with the code that changes the formant of a `wav` file and saves the result to another `wav` file.

Comment: @llogan if you use -strict -2 (with a no root acount), you can mix in a mp4 container, lossess video and audio, for web player, and reduce the final file´s size so much.

Comment: @joys

ffmpeg -i audio1.wav -map 0:0 -codec:a flac -sample_fmt s16 -ac 2 -ar 48000 audio1.flac

audio1.wav is 50% more size and problematic to reproduce than a simple, less, universal and armonic audio1.flac

now, you can manipulate de audio1.flac ffmpeg -i 1.wav -af asetrate=44100*3/4,atempo=4/3,aresample=44100 -c copy -strict -2 audio2.wav

Comment: @xear Incorrect. `-strict -2` is an alias for `-strict experimental`. It has nothing to do with root, lossless video and audio, web players, or file size. It is required when a component is considered experimental to make the user acknowledge this fact. Although many users needlessly add it from rote usage or copy it from outdated commands. Also, you are trying to stream copy and filter the same stream at the same time, but this is not possible. Remove `-c copy`. If you were to try your command the output would tell you this: `Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.`

Comment: @llogan with root only encode video, for the rest, do with ubuntu user. -strict dont exist for root.  "Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together"  with video, but in this post, only sreams audio we have working so ubuntu ffmpeg -i 1.wav -af asetrate=44100*3/4,atempo=4/3,aresample=44100 -c copy 2.wav is correct, and remember, root user only for video, ubuntu use for audio and mix files into contenedor, see it: ffmpeg -i  video.mp4 -i audio.flac  -i audio.mp4 -c copy -map_metadata -1 -map 0:0 -map 2:0  -map 3:0 -strict -2 llogan_final_videoh264origianl_audiolossess_flac_or_ac3.mp4

Comment: ac3 is a lossy audio from audio.flac, obvislyn, how it is experimental, some tv video and flac dont decode, but yes video and ac3, the furure is libx264 avc and flac. Rest is for see in display "no device space left" and go to delete wavs, mkv, etc etc.

Comment: so lloran, can you retracted the -1 vote on the first step answer to resolve Joys' s problem? y have a solution, using panner.setPosition(X, Y, Z)

Comment: @xear I did not downvote your answer. You can't filter and stream copy audio at the same time. Try your commands. They will fail.